# how to change the color of rating field on click?

Tags: javascript, angular

can we change the color of rating field (`*`) when user click on star (`*`) .Example when user click on third start `*`  so first three star should be `red` .

I am able to get the selected `index` but how to change the color upto clicked star in angular .

here is my code
 https://codesandbox.io/s/r70jn156pm

```
export class AppComponent {
  title = "CodeSandbox";
  arr: [] = [];
  constructor() {
    this.arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
  }

  onClickItem(index) {
    console.log(index);
    /// color should be red
  }
```

HTML

```
<h1>Rating</h1>

<ul>
<li *ngFor="let i of arr;let in =index" (click)="onClickItem(in)">*</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I can only advice you to use a already coded rating plugin.. there are a lot out there which should also work with angular and all you want to achieve is already built ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will defined a class related to selected star and use `[ngClass]`

app.component.ts

```
export class AppComponent {
  title = "CodeSandbox";
  arr: any[] = [];
  selectedRate:number = -1;
  constructor() {
    this.arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
  }
  onClickItem(index) {
    this.selectedRate=index
  }
}
```

app.component.css

```
li.selected { 
  color: red;
}
```

app.template.html

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let i of arr;let in =index" (click)="onClickItem(in)" 
                      [ngClass]="{selected:in <= selectedRate}">*</li>
</ul>
```

Happy Coding.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [style.color]

```
<h1>Rating</h1>
<div [style.color]="index==0?'gray':index==1?'red':index==2?'blue':index==3?'yellow':'black'">
<ul >
<li *ngFor="let i of arr;let in =index" [style.color]="in>index?'gray':'inherit'"
                (click)="onClickItem(in)">*</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

That's. depending the value of the variable "index", all goes in color indicate by ternary operator. But, inside the li, the color becomes gray if "in < index". else when we click all the "*" goes in color indicate by the div

In your .ts

```
index:number=0;
onClickItem(index) {
    console.log(index);
    this.index=index;
  }
```

And remove the line in your .css

```
li
{
   color:gray //<--remove this line
   ...
}
```

color:

Answer (score 1):

Basically if you can handle `onClick` and you can caputre index of clicked element, you can just store clicked index element in controller and use conditional rendering on template using `[ngClass]` directive:

```
<ul>
<li *ngFor="let i of arr;let in =index" (click)="onClickItem(in)" [ngClass]="getStarClass(in)">*</li>
</ul>
```

in controller:

```
onClickItem(in) {
  this.clickedIdx = in
}

getStarClass(in: number) {
  if (in >= this.clickedIdx) return { 'color-gray': true, 'color-red': false }
  else return { 'color-gray': false, 'color-red': true}
}
```

IMHO I'd avoid using `[style.color]` directive binding just for sake of non mixing styling with document structure. For sure you then need to define those two css classes to handle up styling