# Angular: star rating

Tags: html, css, angular

I would like implement rating star system.  After click returns correct value of star. I have a problem with correctly displaying the selected stars. Just like in this picture, it doesn't show me 3 stars in yellow. How to change it? [image: rating star]**Component:**

```
 export class RatingStarComponent implements OnInit {
  stars: number[] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
  constructor() { }
  ngOnInit() {
  }
  countStar(star) {
    console.log('Value of star', star);
  }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
      <ul class="list-inline rating-list" *ngFor="let star of stars" style="display: inline-block" >
          <li (click)="countStar(star)"><i   class="fa fa-star "></i></li> 
      </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
  .rating-list li {
  float: right;
  color: #ddd;
  padding: 10px 5px;

}

.rating-list li:hover,
.rating-list li:hover ~ li {
  color: #ffd700;
}

.rating-list {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
}
```

Any help or suggestion is welcome.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to change the color of rating field on click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51436008/how-to-change-the-color-of-rating-field-on-click)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have to store the selected value:

```
countStar(star) {
    this.selectedValue = star;
    console.log('Value of star', star);
}
```

And add class which will change color of the star for all the stars with less or equal rating:

```
.rating-list li.selected {
    color: #ffd700;
}
```

```
<li (click)="countStar(star)"
    [ngClass]="{'selected': (star <= selectedValue)}">
        <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
</li>
```

See [full example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-m17rjg) for the details.

Comment: saved me hours of efforts, this is very easy to implement using pure angular, without using any external css javascript framework.

Answer (score 7):

**Improved version**

In this solution, even on hover all previous stars' colors will change to yellow:

**HTML**:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
      <ul class="list-inline rating-list" *ngFor="let star of stars; let i= index" style="display: inline-block"> 
          <li (click)="countStar(star)" id="{{'starId'+i}}" [ngClass]="{'selected': (star <= selectedValue)}" 
           (mouseover)="addClass(star)" (mouseout)="removeClass(star)"> ★
          </li>
      </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Component.ts**:

```
stars: number[] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
selectedValue: number = 0;

countStar(star) {
    this.selectedValue = star;
  }

addClass(star) {
   let ab = "";
   for (let i = 0; i < star; i++) {
     ab = "starId" + i;
     document.getElementById(ab).classList.add("selected");
   }
}
removeClass(star) {
   let ab = "";
   for (let i = star-1; i >= this.selectedValue; i--) {
     ab = "starId" + i;
     document.getElementById(ab).classList.remove("selected");
   }
}
```

**SCSS**:

```
.rating-list {
    li {
    font-size: 20px;
        float: right;
        color: #ddd;
        padding: 10px 5px;
        &:hover {
            color: #ffd700;
            ~ {
                li {
                    color: #ffd700;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    li.selected {
        color: #ffd700;
    }
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
}
```

See [this example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-scss-demo-dj1wwo) for details.

Answer (score 0):

I tried using material Icon. It's working.

**HTML**:

```
<ul class="list-inline rating-list" *ngFor="let star of stars; let i= index">
    <li (click)="countStar(star)" [ngClass]="{'selected': (star <= selectedValue)}" (mouseover)="addClass(star)"
         (mouseout)="removeClass()"> <span class="material-icons">star</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**ts**

```
stars: number[] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
selectedValue: number = 0;
isMouseover = true;

countStar(star: number) {
  this.isMouseover = false;
  this.selectedValue = star;
}

 addClass(star: number) {
  if (this.isMouseover) {
    this.selectedValue = star;
  }
 }

 removeClass() {
   if (this.isMouseover) {
      this.selectedValue = 0;
   }
 }
```

**CSS**

```
.rating-list {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
}
.rating-list li {
  font-size: 20px;
  float: right;
  color: #ddd;
  padding: 10px 5px;
}
.rating-list li:hover {
  color: #ffd700;
}
.rating-list li:hover ~ li {
  color: #ffd700;
}
.rating-list li.selected {
  color: #ffd700;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Variation of Mohit's solution**

I adjusted Mohit's solution to achieve the behavior I was looking for. This will make it so that when you hover over a star that is lower than the current selected rating, the stars above will un-highlight and then go back to the original value if nothing is selected.

```js
addClass(star: number) {
    let ab = '';
    for (let i = 0; i < star; i++) {
      ab = 'starId' + i;
      document.getElementById(ab)?.classList.add('selected');
    }

    for (let i = star; i < 5; i++) {
      ab = 'starId' + i;
      document.getElementById(ab)?.classList.remove('selected');
    }
  }
  removeClass(star: number) {
    let ab = '';
    for (let i = 0; i < this.selectedValue; i++) {
      ab = 'starId' + i;
      document.getElementById(ab)?.classList.add('selected');
    }
    for (let i = star - 1; i >= this.selectedValue; i--) {
      ab = 'starId' + i;
      document.getElementById(ab)?.classList.remove('selected');
    }
  }
```